# Git post-commit /post-receive hook not working

Tags: linux, git

I have a Git repo one one server. i want that whenever an admin pushes changes to git repo, those changes may automatically be deployed to a folder on the same server, where git repo is hosted.

As my repo is in /opt/myrepo.git , i have created the scripts /opt/myrepo.git/hooks/post-commit .

when i perform any commit on the repo, the above script should run, but it does not. i have wrote simple Echo commands in it to test its output to a file, but it doesnt run at all.

Comment: Is the `post-commit` file executable (`chmod +x /opt/myrepo.git/hooks/post-commit`)?

Comment: yes, obviously it is

Comment: @Farhan have you figured out the issue? can you please share what you did to make it work?

Comment: still not resolved :(

Comment: Describing "it's broken" isn't particularly helpful. You should show exactly where each repo is, show the hook files and their permissions and **demonstrate the problem**. Did you already [search for dupliates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=post-receive+git)? This is more of an SO question than SF IMO.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have exactly one as well. I can't figure out what is it a problem. Everything looks fine. But I have to run hook manually.

Answer (score 2):

For pushes you should use the post-receive hook and not the post-commit hook.

I made the same mistake due to the odd naming convention

Comment: tried with post-receive as well, didnt worked

Comment: I know it sounds obvious but have you tried just running your script manually e.g. /opt/myrepo.git/hooks/post-commit just to check there are no typos at the start

Comment: yes, when manually run,it works fine

Comment: It worked for me with `1.7`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using the post-hook you should make sure that the your hook file is executable. So take a look at the file permissions make sure that you have chmoded the file to a+x.

`chmod a+x post-receive`

post-receive hook should be executable by git. If its not executable then git doesn't inform you.

Also, make sure the first line is #!/bin/sh

Hope this helps